# My Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS Looks Weird

Tags: unity, themes

When I click on my directory file, the directory list looks wired.

When I click on any type of OS menu, it's look very bad.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you install a new theme?

Comment: No I don't install any them